# Extending singleton class with private properties

Tags: javascript

I have a singleton class that I want to extend. Without extending the class it's fine but get
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot initialize #b twice on the same object` if I use the extended version.

```
class A{
    static #instance = null
    #a = 1
    constructor(){
        if(!A.#instance){
            A.#instance = this
        }
        return A.#instance
    }
}

class B extends A{
    #b = 2
}
```

`[new A(),new A()]` works

`[new B(),new B()]` throws an error.

Comment: @Yogi check my solution, looks awesome. posted it in the question you gave link to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a flaw in your A::constructor():
From the constructor you return the first created instance of A saved in a static property thus reusing it as a parent instance of all instances of the class B.
Thus you try to initialize the same `#b` twice which throws.

To implement your singleton design pattern you could proxify the classes (luckily we can proxify a JS class!):

```js
const proxify = (what) => new Proxy(what, {
    instance: null,
    construct(B, args) {
        return this.instance ??= new what(...args);
    }
});

const A = proxify(class {
    #a = 1
    c = 0
});

const B = proxify(class extends A {
    #b = 2
    d = 0
});

// make sure we have a singleton for A

const a1 = new A;
const a2 = new A;
a2.c = 1;

console.log(a1.c, a2.c);

// make sure we have a singleton for B

const b1 = new B;
const b2 = new B;
b1.c = 2;
b2.d = 3;

console.log(b1.c, b2.c);
console.log(b1.d, b2.d);
```

Comment: Thanks. The combination of your comment and the Yogi's link helped me reach solution I was happy with. Basically adding a check that the saved instance was created by the same/correct constructor.

>From the constructor you return the first created instance of A saved in a static property thus reusing it as a parent instance of all instances of the class B. Thus you try to initialize the same #b twice which throws.

Comment: You're welcome. My solution is awesome for me, I didn't do such things before. I like that we can now do such things in JS. The Proxy is awesome thing, playing with it recently and amazed